# Where are ServiceWorker data stored?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, web-applications, service-worker

I'm playing with ServiceWorker api for quite a while, but cannot figure out, where are the cached files stored on my hard drive and if they're accessible from outside of browser context. Any tips highly appreciated!

Cheers,
Wojtek

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For Firefox, in the `storage` subdirectory of your Firefox profile.

E.g. ~/.mozilla/firefox/z4o9asac.default/storage/default/http+++localhost+3003/cache

Comment: thanks! I found out that cached content is stored just in clear text there :)

Answer (score 0):

The only thing I found is a directory 
`~/.config/google-chrome/Profile 1/Service Worker` (on Ubuntu), but it seems to be just SW implementation there.